# Migrated Google Sign-In to use new Sign In with Google library but still receiving notifications

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I have an app that used the [Google Sign-in JavaScript library](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) that used the following script tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=initializeGoogleApi" async defer></script>
```

I followed the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/migration) and updated to use Google Identity Services library. I replaced the script tag above with this one.

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

However, I'm still receiving notifications from Google that are saying "One or more of your web applications uses the legacy Google Sign-In JavaScript library. Please migrate your project(s) to the new Google Identity Services SDK before March 31, 2023".

I can't see why I am still receiving these messages. Is there somewhere in Google Cloud where I can see where the legacy sign in is still being used? Is there another reason why I'm still receiving these notifications?

Answer (score 0):

Google has a system that detects if you are using the endpoint.  They then send you an email.

This email queue is a little long so they may have detected it before you upgraded and are only now getting around to sending you the email about it.

If you know you have upgraded then your good don't worry about it.